# How to handle validation errors in laravel5.1 using ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

Im creating a validation now using laravel5.1 with ajax of jquery. Everything works fine. But, what I want is to display the errors each `<inputs>` just like when using validation without ajax. Please see my code below, and the picture for the sample output. I've also tried it with `@if` of blade(laravel), but not working.

**Note**: *Im using bootstrap framework too.*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="result">
        <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post" id="create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price" class="control-label">Price</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>

            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = '{{ route('ajax-push') }}';
        var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        $('#create').on('submit', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: { _token: token },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    $('#result').removeClass('alert').removeClass('alert-danger');
                    $('#result > ul').empty();
                    $.each(errors, function(i, item){
                        $('#result').addClass('alert').addClass('alert-danger');
                        $('#result > ul').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function postAjaxCreate(Request $request){
        $validator = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|min:2',
            'type' => 'required|max:255',
            'price' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200)->with($validator->messages());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the from data to the ajax request

`data: $('#create').serialize(),`

and most likely  the response doesn't have a responseJSON property, and you are sending the data twice from, remove the with function in you php function

Add the errors to the page using something similar to the following js:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){
  $('#'+i).addClass('alert alert-danger'); 
  ('#'+i).after('<p>' + item + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: Nice. Great work. But how about the error handling base on the picture?

Comment: you get the input fields based on the property names of the errors then you append the errors to the page/update the input class

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: @Jonjie yes i can

Comment: I got it now dude.

Comment: Ooh... sorry :)